# Delay loading Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, loading

I'm building a site that has a lot of Javascript formatting the front page.  Because it is a CMS it also has a lot of php and mysql.  The problem is that when the page loads, for about two seconds, the HTML, php and CSS is visible, but the javascript has not yet reformatted the page.

Is there a way to make the javascript load faster, or even just hide specific parts of the page for a second or two.  I've seen loading gifs and that would be perfect, but I can't find a place to implement them.  Are they CSS based?

Any hints or even a link to another page would be helpful.

Comment: You could just generate the right HTML and CSS on the server side from the outset...

Comment: Actually I can't.  I'm using a content management system.  The amount of manipulation I can do is extremely limited.

Answer (score 1):

Add in your css `display: none` to your main content or what have you, then at the end of the javascript have it `mainContent.show()`  (assuming jQuery)